# What's the meaning of different braces?

Tags: calculus, rolles-theorem

> Since the function $f(x)$ is continuous in the closed interval $[a,b]$ and differentiable in the open interval $(a,b)$, so the function $F(x)$ will be continuous in the interval $[a,b]$ and satisfied all the conditions of Rolle's theorem.

In above text, they had used third braces `[]` when talking about continuous of a function. And, they used first braces `()` when talking about differentiability. Is there any deep meaning of different braces? All the things I know that is there's no differences, Is there?

Comment: [Closed vs open interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(mathematics))

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA So, third braces used for closed and, ........?

Comment: $(a,b]=\{x\in \Bbb R\ |\ a<x\leq b\}$

Comment: @C.F.G Half opened and half closed interval.. But,,, I can't find answer of my question..

Comment: $[a,b]=\{x\in \Bbb R\ |\ a\leq x\leq b\}$ and $(a,b)=\{x\in \Bbb R\ |\ a<x< b\}$

Comment: @C.F.G understood.. That's what MauroALLEGRANZA said

Comment: They are often used in this context to indicate whether the endpoint is included (square) or excluded (round) and can be mixed - though normally it is open and closed intervals which are most interesting.

Comment: Consider $f(x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}$ from $x=-1$ to $x=1$ giving a semicircle.  You want to use $f(-1)=0$ and $f(1)=0$ so a closed interval $[-1,1]$ including the endpoints for Rolle's theorem, but the function does not have a finite derivative at the end-points, but does on the open interval $(-1,1)$ excluding the endpoints

Comment: Btw., what is the meaning of "first" and "third" in the context of parentheses?

Comment: @Henry -1 is for x axis. And, 1 is for y axis,isn't it? But, i can see something else from your comment

Comment: @Istiak No.  In my example "$x=−1$ to $x=1$" is the range of values of $x$ being considered and the brackets indicate whether the endpoints are included or not.